# MySQL date formats - difficulty Inserting a date

Tags: mysql, date, insert, format

I am trying to further a question I asked yesterday where I wanted to know how to query a date in a different format. But now I am trying to do an insert using this method (see below) however I can't get it to work. I have checked the manual but it is not beginner friendly!

```
INSERT INTO custorder VALUES ('Kevin','yes'), STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: Wrong placement of single quotes '

Comment: was the -1 vote because I put in a php tag... sorry. it was because I am using php variables.. wasnt thinking!

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Put the date in single quotes and move the parenthesis (after the `'yes'`) to the end:

```
INSERT INTO custorder 
  VALUES ('Kevin', 'yes' , STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y') ) ;
                        ^                                     ^
---parenthesis removed--|                and added here ------|
```

---

But you can always use dates without `STR_TO_DATE()` function, just use the (Y-m-d) `'20120101'` or `'2012-01-01'` format. Check the MySQL docs: [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

```
INSERT INTO custorder 
  VALUES ('Kevin', 'yes', '2012-01-01') ;
```

Comment: Thank You for pointing me to the Date and Time Literals chapter. Now I understand when I insert 20120101 or "20120101" into date field MySQL recognizes it. I thought it was PHP magic or a glitch.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you've not encapsulated your string properly. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO custorder VALUES ('Kevin','yes'), STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Alternatively, you can do the following but it is not recommended. Make sure that you use STR_TO-DATE it is because when you are developing web applications you have to explicitly convert String to Date which is annoying. Use first One.

INSERT INTO custorder VALUES ('Kevin','yes'), '2012-01-01';

I'm not confident that the above SQL is valid, however, and you may want to move the date part into the brackets. If you can provide the exact error you're getting, I might be able to more directly help with the issue.

Answer (score 10):

The date format for mysql insert query is `YYYY-MM-DD`

example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (date_column) VALUE ('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 3):

An add-on to the previous answers since I came across this concern:

If you really want to insert something like `24-May-2005` to your **DATE** column, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO someTable(Empid,Date_Joined)
VALUES
    ('S710',STR_TO_DATE('24-May-2005', '%d-%M-%Y'));
```

In the above query please note that if it's `May`(ie: the month in letters) the format should be `%M`.

**NOTE**: I tried this with the latest MySQL version 8.0 and it works!

Answer (score 3):

When using a string-typed variable in PHP containing a date, the variable must be enclosed in single quotes:

```
$NEW_DATE = '1997-07-15';
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (NEW_DATE, ...) VALUES ('$NEW_DATE', ...)";
```

Comment: I've tested this is true for both MySQL and SQLite