# SQL date format is showing blank result (using jQuery e.g. 00-00-0000)

Tags: jquery, mysql, calendar

[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrqtl.png)I am creating a calendar using jQuery and when I submit the date, it stores in my SQL table but as a blank result e.g. instead of '09-07-2017' it shows '00-00-0000', can someone help me? Here is my code:

```
    Index.PHP:

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper"> 
    <form class="calendar-form" action="button.inc.php" method="POST">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",


        } );
      } );
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Check Availability</button>

    </body>
    </html>
    Button.Inc.PHP:

  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'database.inc.php';

    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['datepicker']);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO system (date) VALUES ('$date');";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



}

?>
    Dbh.Inc.PHP:

<?php


$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "calendar";

$conn = mysqli_connect ($dbServername,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, the formatting of both the SQL and jQuery are the same but for some reason the SQL wont store the date properly.

This is the output:

[image: database]

[image: mysql]

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907210/mysql-date-formats-difficulty-inserting-a-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default date format in MySQL is `yyyy-mm-dd`, not `dd-mm-yy` which is what you're using in jQuery DatePicker. You can either format the date before you send it to the database, or you can use the `altField` feature of the DatePicker to provide the alternative format like this:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            altField: "#mysql_date",
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="mysql_date" name="mysql_date" />
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" /></p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Check Availability</button>
</form>
```

Note: I've added a `<form>` because I see it missing in your code, and I've also added the `name` attribute to the `input` boxes because it is needed for proper form submission.